# Creating random image flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Basically I'm trying to make a skull flicker over a persons face, I've achieved it flashing up once. But the effect I'm trying to achieve is that it looks more organic and random. Here's the basic structure:

```
    function flicker() {

        var maxFlick = 6,
            amount = Math.round(Math.random() * maxFlick),
            running = false;

        function showHide() {

            $flicker.show();

            running = true;

            setTimeout(function() {
                $flicker.hide();

                running = false;

            }, 100)
        }
        for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            if(!running) {
                showHide();
            }
        }           
    }

    setInterval(flicker, 4000);
```

I had presumed that running a for loop with a random amount statement would produce the desired effect, but it's still only flashing up once every 4000milliseconds as previously. Any pointers?

Comment: 1. You run `for` first iteration, `running` is `false`. 2. Since `running` is `false`, `showHide` function is called. 3. `running` is set to `true` in `showHide` function. 4. You run all other `for` iteration **in a couple of milliseconds**, having `running` as `true` in all these iterations. It sounds like you coded not what you have in mind.

Comment: The "running" variable is there as an attempt to stop the for loop from iterating so quickly. So that once running is set back to false it can run the loop again. Though I realise now that it will just return back to the loop statement having not run anything if running=true when it's iterating. I think the solution must be to cause a delay inside the loop that matches the setTimeout delay inside showHide()?

Comment: Yes, you can, for example. do something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mspv8d6h/1/).

Comment: Thank you, that's given me enough to go on!

Comment: You're welcome. Well, every solved question in SO should have accepted answer, so either you can delete your question or I can post this code as an answer (if it looks like an answer for you at all).

Comment: Once I've got a fully working piece of code with the desired effect that I described above then I'll write out the answer and attribute you ( or feel free to write out your answer here and I'll accept it and then link the fully working code from a comment!)

Comment: Well, I didn't test my code, but doesn't it do what is required in question?

Comment: Not quite, but it definitely helped got me 90% of the way there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Regent and [this fiddle](/http://jsfiddle.net/mspv8d6h/1/) I came up with the answer:

```
    function flicker() {

        var maxFlick = 6,
            amount = Math.round(Math.random() * maxFlick),
            delta = 2,
            timer;

        var doneFlicks = 0;

        var flickInterval = setInterval(showHide, timer);

        function showHide() {
            timer = Math.round((Math.random() + delta) * 100)

            $flicker.show();

            var hide = setTimeout(function() {
                $flicker.hide();
                doneFlicks++
            }, 20)

            if (doneFlicks == amount) {
                clearInterval(flickInterval);
            }
        }       
    }

    setInterval(flicker, 3000);
```

This produces a randomised flicker effect that's called every 3 seconds - perfect for a horror film effect!

Thanks again to Regent for all the help!